# Jackson - Overriding @JsonIgnore in MixIn

Tags: java, jackson

I have a property that that is @JsonIgnored on a class. And I wanted to make it available on some particular flow. I know that on a subclass, one can just use @JsonIgnored(false), and it overrides the base class annotation.

However, this does not seem to work via the MixIn, what works though is adding the @JsonProperty in the MixIn Interface/Abstract class. However, I am not too sure if this is safe and is consistent behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: Adding `@JsonProperty` should also work, although addition of `@JsonIgnored(false)` definitely should also work. It could be a bug, depending on how old the Jackson version you are using is.